# Bulk Query with PK Chunking via WSC -- error reading extracted records with CSVReader

Tags: batch, bulk-api, wsc

I'm having an issue with the CSVReader class in the Salesforce WSC.
The error I get when trying to read the contents of a batch is "com.sforce.async.CSVReader$CSVParseException: Found unescaped quote. A value with quote should be within a quote".

I don't understand how this could be possible because I am reading directly from a batch extract (query) from Salesforce (and I assume that the Salesforce prepared exported data is properly escaped for all special characters, and in fact can confirm that if I open the CSV from within Salesforce as "View Extract").

I have not made any changes to the data, just trying to read the query records.  I even tried on an object that for sure contains NO data with quotes at all.  So I don't understand what could be causing this.

I know for certain that my query is successful and everything up to that point is working correctly.  I know this from two things:  1) again, I can view the extract in the Salesforce UI via "bulk data load jobs" in setup 2) I can use standard Java bufferedreader to read the contents (but of course this is not preferred as it splits on line breaks within cells, etc...).  I need a proper CSV reader as this is how the data should prepared by the Salesforce query extract.

Here is my code:

```
for (BatchInfo batch : PKBatchInfoList) {
   if(batch.getState() == BatchStateEnum.Completed){
      CSVReader rdr = new CSVReader(bulkConnection.getBatchResultStream(job.getId(), batch.getId()), "UTF-8");
      List<String> resultHeader = rdr.nextRecord();
      System.out.println("used CSV Reader");
    }
}
```